# Either, Or, Both.....a question in mathematical writing

Tags: soft-question, terminology, advice

I want to write that "this transformation changes either rank of effective matrix, or norm of effective matrix, or both"

I want to avoid repeating "of effective matrix". How can I do this

Comment: "This transformation changes either the effective matrix's rank, norm, or both."

Comment: Also, you can just say "...the effective matrix's rank or norm" since the "or" isn't xor.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Perhaps, but I would usually side with clarity over brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This transformation changes at least one of the rank or the norm of the effective matrix." is a clear alternative.

You could also flip it round: "the transformation can't [simultaneously] hold constant both the rank and the norm of the effective matrix".

Answer (score 1):

"this transformation changes either rank or norm of effective matrix"

will do.